# Explicit upper and lower bounds on the Prime counting function and Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds, riemann-hypothesis

I have been researching equivalent statements on the Riemann Hypothesis. Schoenfeld proved that Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to the bound $$|\pi(x) - {\rm Li}(x)| < \frac{1}{8\pi}\sqrt{x}\log x$$
for $x\geq 2657$. Excepting Schoenfeld's explicit bound, I have not been able to find explicit upper and lower bounds on the Prime counting function such that they would imply that Riemann Hypothesis is true.

In particular, I am wondering if they can exist $A$ and $B$ such that $$\frac {x}{\log(x)}+A<\pi(x)<\frac {x}{\log(x)}+B$$ and such that they would imply that Riemann Hypothesis is true.

Can these bounds exist? Are they known?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The lower bound and Upper bound are still unknown and needed to be prove!!!

Comment: $$
A,B =\left( \sum\limits_{k = 2}^{\left\lfloor {\log x} \right\rfloor } {\frac{{(k - 1)!x}}{{\log ^k x}}}  \right)\mp C\sqrt x \log x
$$ would work, with a suitable $C>0$. This is because $$
\operatorname{Li}(x) = \frac{x}{{\log x}} + \left( {\sum\limits_{k = 2}^{\left\lfloor {\log x} \right\rfloor } {\frac{{(k - 1)!x}}{{\log ^k x}}} } \right) + \mathcal{O}(1),
$$ by the optimally truncated asymptotic series of $\operatorname{Li}(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you want $A$ and $B$ to be constants, since you don't indicate any dependence in them on $x$. So you appear to be asking if RH might be equivalent to $\pi(x) = x/\log x + O(1)$ with explicit constants in the role of the $O(1)$ bound.

If you look at the graph at the bottom of the page https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html, where $\pi(x)$ is in red and $x/\log x$ is in green, what it suggests there is true: $\pi(x) - x/\log x \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.  Specifically, the oldest form of the prime number theorem with error term
$$
\pi(x) = {\rm Li}(x) + O(xe^{-c\sqrt{\log x}}) 
$$
implies
$$
\pi(x) = {\rm Li}(x) + O_k\left(\frac{x}{(\log x)^k}\right) 
$$
for all $k > 0$, and integration by parts twice tells us
$$
{\rm Li}(x) = \frac{x}{\log x} + \frac{x}{(\log x)^2} +
O\left(\frac{x}{(\log x)^3}\right), 
$$
and together these estimates imply
$$
\pi(x) = \frac{x}{\log x} + \frac{x}{(\log x)^2} +
O\left(\frac{x}{(\log x)^3}\right),
$$
so $\pi(x) - x/\log x \sim x/(\log x)^2$.  Thus $\pi(x) - x/\log x \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.

In contrast to that, Littlewood proved that the difference $\pi(x) - {\rm Li}(x)$ changes sign infinitely often.

While the Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to $\pi(x) = {\rm Li}(x) + O(\sqrt{x}\log x)$, there is *no* estimate of the form $\pi(x) = x/\log x + O(x^{1-\delta})$ for some $\delta$ in $(0,1)$: using the last displayed estimate on $\pi(x)$ above, if $\pi(x) = x/\log x + O(x^{1-\delta})$ then
$$
\frac{x}{(\log x)^2} = O\left(\frac{x}{(\log x)^3}\right) + O(x^{1-\delta}) = O\left(\frac{x}{(\log x)^3}\right) 
$$
for large $x$, which is false.

The reality is that the use of $x/\log x$ as an approximation for $\pi(x)$ works in the asymptotic estimate in the prime number theorem but *not* in non-asymptotic estimates that you will find in equivalent reformulations of the Riemann hypothesis. We usually write PNT in terms of $x/\log x$ because it has the attraction of being a simple expression in comparison to ${\rm Li}(x)$, but you have to give up on working with $x/\log x$ as an approximation to $\pi(x)$ when you want to look at more sophisticated things like RH.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks @KCd!